# Handling client Creation failiers

Tags: java, android

I am creating a android client app to connect to my server using the following code

```
Socket socket = new Socket(MYIP, PORT);
```

When the server is available it works well , but when the server is not available i want to tell **No server found.**  But unfortunately no any exceptions are thrown and my application freezes.

What is the recommended way to handle this task

Comment: The above code is surrounded by try catch , And this question is specific to android as the above code works perfectly in java SE

Answer (score 0):

It was mentioned in the comments, but are you using an async task when trying to connect to the server? Also what is the timeout on your connection?

It sounds like your application is blocking while it tries to contact the server, but it is taking so long that Android throws an [ANR](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/design/responsiveness.html).